# Cron task stops performing when encounters unredirected stdout/stderr

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I've just learned about cron and I've been messing around with it a little bit but I have some doubts about how is it working. From what I suspect, a task is being stopped from performing if it tries to get/send any I/O from/to terminal? I'm asking because I've chained some commands using && and it looked like anytime there would be a stdout/err that wasn't redirected to a file, the rest of the script wouldn't run.

I'm new to Linux so I maybe get this wrong, I hope some of you could explain to me what happens.

L.E: My task would be

```
* * * * * root apt-get check && apt-get update > /home/user/text.txt && echo "Test" > /home/user/smth.txt
```

And it looked that because stderr wasn't also redirected to text.txt, the task wouldn't continue.

Comment: Let us now what your commands are and  how your crontab file looks like.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write it down.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I've messed up something in the path and that's why I wouldn't see the last echo appended to the file. I'm sorry for wasting your time.  :( I do have one question tho: I can't use cron to schedule tasks which requires user input? Like apt-get upgrade without using -y.

Comment: As far as I know, no you can't.

Comment: `cron` isn't `bash`. Read `man 5 crontab`. Some programs, (`sudo` for sure, maybe `apt-get`) use the `isatty - test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal` call (see `man 3 isatty`) to specifically prevent putting passwords into disk files.